# How to override a fullscreen game with keywindow borderless window (overlay)?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I've created the app which sometimes shows up an overlay with label and textbox. It works nice, but I need it to work even with other apps are in full-screen mode and active.

For overlay, I've create custom window class and overridden `canBecomeKeyWindow` method to let borderless window become the key window (simply returns `YES`).

So it works, but when I run e.g. Minecraft, and then make it full screen, my overlay can override it. But I can't type in NSTextField in the overlay. How to fix it?

I'm creating an overlay like this:

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] hideOtherApplications];
NSRect frame = [[NSScreen mainScreen] frame];
_fadedWindow = [[CustonWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:frame
                                           styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask
                                             backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered
                                            defer:NO];
[_fadedWindow setAcceptsMouseMovedEvents:YES];
[_fadedWindow setOpaque:NO];
[_fadedWindow setLevel:CGShieldingWindowLevel()];
[_fadedWindow setBackgroundColor:[NSColor colorWithDeviceRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.8]];
NSApplicationPresentationOptions options = NSApplicationPresentationDisableProcessSwitching + NSApplicationPresentationHideDock + NSApplicationPresentationDisableForceQuit + NSApplicationPresentationDisableSessionTermination + NSApplicationPresentationDisableHideApplication;
[NSApp setPresentationOptions:options];
_fadedWindow.alphaValue = 0;
[_fadedWindow orderFrontRegardless];
[[_fadedWindow animator] setAlphaValue:1];
[_fadedWindow toggleFullScreen:self];
[_fadedWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
[NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
[_fadedWindow orderFront:self];
```

But still, I can't seem to populate overlay's NSTextField with keyboard input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Create a subclass for _fadedWindow. Then put this in:

```
-(BOOL)canBecomeKeyWindow {
    return YES;
}
```