# OSX overlay on native FullscreenMode

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, overlay

Our application needs to overlay to fullscreen. With regular fullscreen (Browser Flash Fullscreen like Prezi or Youtube) it works, but with native fullscreen (Lion Fullscreen, Fullscreen mode, other space) it won't...

The question is, how can I force the window, to appear over Fullscreen mode, and KeyNote fullscreen?

Sample app:
_window is an NSWindow (NSPanel wont work either)

```
- (void) activeSpaceDidChange:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
        if ([_window isVisible] && ![_window isOnActiveSpace])
            [_window orderOut:self];

        [_window setCollectionBehavior: NSWindowCollectionBehaviorCanJoinAllSpaces | NSWindowCollectionBehaviorFullScreenAuxiliary];
        [_window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
        [_window setCollectionBehavior:NSWindowCollectionBehaviorMoveToActiveSpace | NSWindowCollectionBehaviorFullScreenAuxiliary];
}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{        
    [_window setCollectionBehavior: NSWindowCollectionBehaviorCanJoinAllSpaces | NSWindowCollectionBehaviorFullScreenAuxiliary];

    [_window orderFrontRegardless];
    [_window setLevel:NSStatusWindowLevel];
    [_window setHidesOnDeactivate: NO];

    [[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(activeSpaceDidChange:) name:NSWorkspaceActiveSpaceDidChangeNotification object:nil];
}
```

**Edit:**

Now with the snippet from Tyler the panel works with FullScreen mode, but unfortunately not with KeyNote fullscreen.

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    [_window setStyleMask:NSUtilityWindowMask | NSNonactivatingPanelMask];
    [_window setLevel:NSFloatingWindowLevel];
    [_window setCollectionBehavior:NSWindowCollectionBehaviorCanJoinAllSpaces|NSWindowCollectionBehaviorFullScreenAuxiliary];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should not require the "activeSpaceDidChange" notification lines and it does seem to need to be an NSPanel. In your applicationDidFinishLaunching just having the following should do it:

```
[_window setStyleMask:NSUtilityWindowMask | NSNonactivatingPanelMask];
[_window setLevel:NSFloatingWindowLevel];
[_window setCollectionBehavior:NSWindowCollectionBehaviorCanJoinAllSpaces|NSWindowCollectionBehaviorFullScreenAuxiliary];
```

Comment: Unfortunately it won't work with KeyNote fullscreen, but at least it works with FSMode. Thanks :)

Comment: This user states success with full screen games, but I could not get it to work with full screen Mail on Mountain Lion. Maybe it works for KeyNote? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13418343/how-to-override-a-fullscreen-game-with-keywindow-borderless-window-overlay

Comment: Try setting the level higher, such as: [_window setLevel:CGShieldingWindowLevel()+10];